# How to make a method object in java and use it?

Tags: java, methods

I am having a tough time understanding the mistake. The mistake is somewhere in the object making or using. VS code is showing me `calIncom cannot be resolved to a typeJava(16777218)`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class incomtax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int salary;
        System.out.println("Give the salary");
        salary = sc.nextInt();
        calIncom obj = new calIncom();
        obj(salary);
    }

    public void calIncom(int a) {
        if (a <= 50000) {
            System.out.println("No incom tax");
        }

        else if (a <= 60000 && a > 50000) {
            System.out.println("Your incom tax is: " + a / 10);
        } else if (a <= 150000 && a > 60000) {
            System.out.println("Your incom tax is: " + a / 20);
        } else if (a >= 150000) {
            System.out.println("Your incom tax is: " + a / 30);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to declare a variable of type `calIncom`. But there is no such type, only a method.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in Java. Methods are not classes.

You have to create an instance of the incomtax class

```
incomtax  obj = new incomtax(); 
obj.calIncom(salary);
```

Comment: or make calIncom static so you can simply call it without having to create the object